# Delphi. Потоки? Как?

Tags: delphi, потоки-данных

Здравствуйте, эксперты!
Здравствуйте, никогда не работал с потоками, но вот появилась задача для которой нужны именно потоки.

Собственно у меня есть список сайтов, есть процедура, которая делает гет запрос парсит, то что мне нужно, записывает в переменную. Собственно как это сделать с помощью потоков? ниже приведен полный листинг примера, то что прога делает теперь, повторяюсь, это только пример.

Зарание спасибо!

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient,
  IdHTTP, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure pars(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5:string);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
type
sp1=record
title:string[150];
purl:string[200];
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
i,n,t:integer;
title,rss,html,title1,title2:WideString;
mas,mas1,mas2,mas3:array[1..50]of sp1;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.pars(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5:string);
var
i,n:integer;
begin
rss:=IdHTTP1.Get(s1);
   n:=1;
   i:=1;
   title:='';
   while (i<=length(rss)) do
    begin
     if pos(s2,rss)<>0 then
      begin
      Delete(rss,1,pos(s2,rss)+length(s2)-1);
       title:=copy(rss,1,pos(s3,rss)-1);
       memo1.lines.add(title);
       mas[n].title:=title;

       Delete(rss,1,pos(s4,rss)+length(s4)-1);
       title:=copy(rss,1,pos(s5,rss)-1);
       memo1.lines.add(title);
       mas[n].purl:=title;

       n:=n+1;
       Application.ProcessMessages();
      end else break;

      end;

     inc(i);
Application.ProcessMessages();

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
pars('http://filmix.net/',''' title=''','''  /></a>','<a href="','">смотреть онлайн »');
mas1:=mas;

pars('http://bigcinema.tv/','</span></li></ul></div><div class="topic_info"><h2 class="title">','</h2>','<!-- / tag groups--><a href="','" class="watch" title="');
mas2:=mas;

end;
```

end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай новый поток. (В менюшке нажимаешь `new` далее `others` и ищешь там `Thread object`)
Копируешь тело процедуры парс в процедуру потока `execute`.
Когда нужно создаешь в коде новый поток(`threadobject` который ты создал будет объектом. Далее объявляешь переменную тип которой будет твой объект.(`var x:TThreadObject;`) Код инициализации будет примерно такой `x:=TThreadObject.create(false); x.execute;`)